# adt wrong android sdk tools revision

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I downloaded the latest ADT and when I start Eclipse I get a message:

This version of ADT requires Android SDK Tools revision 22.2.1 or above. Current version is 10.0.0.

SDK manager shows that I have revision 22.6.1 installed.

I have tried the steps I found in some other questions of this type - none of it helped. But this isn't an update it is a brand new install so I can't understand why it thinks the SDK Tools is so old.